# Dynamically setting validations object in Ember- ember-validations

Tags: javascript, validation, ember.js

Using [dockyard/ember-validations](http://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations)The default way of setting validation rule is like below.

```
var Controller = Em.Controller.extend( 

{

validations:  {
'model.firstName':
  {presence:
    {message: 'First Name is a required field.'}
  },
'model.lastName':
  {presence:
    {message: 'Last Name is a required field.'}
  }  
},

..

}
```

But  I want to choose this validations object based on a condition, I choosen as a function property like below.

```
var Controller = Em.Controller.extend( 

{

validations: function() {
if(somecondition)
{
return{ 'model.firstName':
  {presence:
    {message: 'First Name is a required field.'}
  },
'model.lastName':
  {presence:
    {message: 'Last Name is a required field.'}
  }  
}
else
{..}
 }

 }.property(),

..

}
```

But when I am converting this as a function ember-validations library is not working as expected. How can i  mitigate this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved by keeping validations as a property itself, and initialized the same using init `init` method of the controller.

```
var Controller = Em.Controller.extend( 

{

  validations: null,

  init:function(){

  this._super();

  if(somecondition){

  this.set('validations',{...});

  }
  else{

   this.set('validations',{...});

  }

  },

 ..

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at [ember-cp-validations](https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-cp-validations), it offers extended options for validation.

Comment: Thanks.. But as I am trying to modify a piece of existing code, dockyard/ember-validations is only option in front of me..